# Has the Apps Script GUI Builder been discontinued?

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script

I just learned that Apps Script is supposed to have a GUI builder, where you can drag and drop objects to create code.  Supposedly it's accessible through the `File` menu, but there is no `Build a user interface` option available on my Apps Script `File` menu?

Comment: Discontinued ages ago. Not in the docs either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GUI builder was discontinued - in September 2013 if I remember correctly.

Comment: Even though you are full of GAS, I guess I'll believe you.  LOL